# Firebase: How to persist user feed after iOS app is killed and restarted

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a `TableView` in my app that loads a user's feed from the Firebase Database when the app is launched. Right now, if the user kills the app and reopens it, the `TableView` is completely blank and it calls the `retrieveFeed` function to retrieve the ten most recent posts again. I would like these posts to load in from the device locally rather than be called from the database server.

It's my understanding from reading the Firebase docs that this offline capability can be added by enabling persistence and setting `keepSynced` to `true` as I do in the code below.  Do I need to use Core Data in order to keep the most recent ten posts in the feed in storage after the app is killed and restarted or should Firebase be capable of this?

In my `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
FirebaseApp.configure()
Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true
```

In my `DataService.swift` (which has all the calls to Firebase):

```
func retrieveFeed(queryNumber: UInt,  lastSeenKey: String?, completion: @escaping ([ Int: DataService.FeedQuote ]) -> ()){
    var dbquery = DatabaseQuery()
    if (lastSeenKey == nil){
        dbquery = self.user_ref.child(self.currentUserUserId).child("feed").queryOrderedByKey().queryLimited(toFirst: queryNumber)
    }
    else {
        dbquery = self.user_ref.child(self.currentUserUserId).child("feed").queryOrderedByKey().queryStarting(atValue: lastSeenKey).queryLimited(toFirst: queryNumber)
    }
    dbquery.keepSynced(true)
    dbquery.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        var FeedQuotes = [DataService.FeedQuote]()
        // ...
        // Data processing here
        // ...
        completion(correctlyOrderedFeedQuotes)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized my error : Inside my function `retrieveFeed` I was also making calls to FirebaseStorage to retrieve images (which Firebase doesn't currently support caching of).  These calls weren't completing properly with the persistence and syncing set up.  Once I adjusted those calls using this pod (https://github.com/antonyharfield/FirebaseStorageCache), it started working!